# DB2-JSON facing -440 sql error while using JSON_VAL for indexing

Tags: json, db2, mainframe, db2-zos, nosql

i'm ok with insertion and selecting, but when i'm trying to retrieve particular document from table while using JSON_VAL index, i'm facing error with sql code -440.

Comment: Did you obtain and review all the information which is available to you? What conclusions did you draw after that? You also need an actual question (in the body of the question, the title is for a title) and almost certainly an example of the code which is causing you the problem, with the full diagnostic information that is available.

Comment: SQL return code -440: NO AUTHORIZED routine-type BY THE NAME routine-name HAVING COMPATIBLE ARGUMENTS WAS FOUND  seeing as the last error was that module was not defined, I am guessing the routine you are calling in this instance also is not setup

Comment: @SaggingRufus you mean that it also the part of admin work in defining the routine, correct?

Comment: Perhaps, I am not familiar with your JSON library, but DB2 is telling you that the routine you are calling is not properly authorized to run.

Comment: If you post the complete error-information and the code you are using to access the DB we could perhaps see if you are calling a procedure the wrong way or if the DB-setup is incorrect.