# How to invoke json_val function in db2 json?

Tags: json, stored-procedures, db2, db2-zos, nosql

I'm trying to index a particular value from stored DB2 nosql, for that I'm using json_val but I need to invoke UDF SYSTOOLS.BSON2JSON to the `json_val` and need to point the table from where I required data.

```
SELECT SYSTOOLS.BSON2JSON(CUSTOMERDATA)
FROM  JSONPO
WHERE YEAR(JSON_VAL(CUSTOMERDATA,'PO.@orderDate', 'd')) = 2017;
```

The above query resulting in sql error -440 so I need to invoke the json_val. How would I invoke it? How would I write stored procedure for it?

Comment: The -440 error means that DB2 can't find a function. You have 2 functions in your statement, (`BSON2JSON` and `JSON_VAL`), but without a full error message we can't guess which one is the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DB2-JSON facing -440 sql error while using JSON\_VAL for indexing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42155988/db2-json-facing-440-sql-error-while-using-json-val-for-indexing)

Comment: @IanBjorhovde To retrieve the value of certain field in a JSON document, we need to invoke a JSON_VAL function. It's a built-in function that provides an SQL interface to extract and retrieve JSON data into SQL data types from BSON objects. Its schema is SYSIBM. This function only accepts the BSON type of JSON document. So its argument needs to be a column from the table that contains JSON document in BSON format or a SYSTOOLS.JSON2BON function that returns the BSON format of JSON document. so here when i'm using the above mentioned query i the error. can't able to predict this.

Comment: What is the datatype of `CUSTOMERDATA`? could you show the DDL of `JSONPO?`

Comment: @piet.t                                                 
CREATE TABLE  JSONPO (                                   
                     ID INTEGER NOT NULL,                
                     CUSTOMER DATA BLOB(16M) INLINE LENGTH 25000, 
                     PRIMARY KEY(ID))                    
                     CCSID UNICODE;

Answer (score 0):

In the year 2017, it should be called as SYSTOOLS.JSON_VAL if your database is enabled for JSON data. I see in your query, the schema name is missing.
In latest version of db2 as of today, your query should work. For more info, you can refer db2 documentation here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-json-val